# How to get all keywords inside a category as a single list in content delivery.net

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, taxonomy

I'm using Tridion 2013, I need a flat list of all keyword inside a `category` using Content Delivery.Net and also how to use filter on category like If I want to get a keyword based on a specific key or keyword name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
var filter = new CompositeFilter();
// all keywords 
filter.DepthFiltering(DepthFilter.UnlimitedDepth, DepthFilter.FilterDown);
// Creates a flat list
TaxonomyFormatter formatter = new TaxonomyListFormatter();
Keyword keywords = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeywords(categoryId, filter, formatter);
IList keywordList = keywords.KeywordChildren; // list of Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.Keyword
```

Do note that when retrieving a flat list like this, you will lose all the information about hierarchy in the Taxonomy, which means that if you want to get the parent keyword of a keyword, you need to fetch that keyword again.

Comment: So this looks to be exactly what I am after but I need to add a Taxonomy filter so I only get a part of the Taxonomy tree. I can't figure out however how to create a TaxonomyFilter. That is an abstract class with no defined methods I am suppose to implement exact "Dispose." So when I do filter.AddTaxonomyFilter( <what do I give it>)?

Comment: You need to instantiate a class that inherits from TaxonomyFilter. In the example above that is: var filter = new CompositeFilter();. You probably don't need to call the AddTaxonomyFilter method :)

Comment: Thanks. I get that concept but that abstract class only has one method on it of Dispose. So If I create a class based on that what method or property do I put on it so it knows what to call or look at to know what filter I want?

Comment: Sorry for being dumb. I connected the dot. I need to use some of the already created classes like AbstractKeywordFilter. That class name threw me off as I assume it was only good for Abstract keywords. I still need to filter the keyword list for only a subset of the keywords but I think I am going at it the wrong direction and instead need to get the keyword object so I can get its parents versus trying to filter a query against the TaxonomyList.

Comment: No worries - this stuff can be confusing ;)